# JQuery hide rows when specific column row value is null

Tags: jquery, hide, show-hide

Having the following table how can i use jquery to only return the rows where the person has a phone no?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>E-mail</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>123456</td>
    <td>john@john.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>joe@joe.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Phil</td>
    <td>654321</td>
    <td>phil@phil.com</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

E.g only John and Phil would be shown since only they have phone no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('table').parent().children().find("td:nth-child(2):empty").parent().hide();
```

Demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/gLwevx2u/